# Does the Z pass works with OpenEXR?

Tags: rendering, file-format, render-passes, depth-of-field

the Defocus (with use Z buffer checked) works perfectly with a render layer node (tested on one frame per time).

however when i rendered the whole  sequence as an OpenEXR (Multilayer or not)  and imported to another blend file it works no more.

I don't see a difference between the too Z passes. Is this a normal thing ? Does saving the Z pass as another format will solve this ? i want to know before i re-render the sequence.

Comment: EXR should work fine, as a matter of fact it is the best format to store the z-pass linerarly and with no distortion. Are you sure that you saved the Z pass as part of your file? Was the Depth socket connected to the Z input on the output node? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. We don't know how you set up your project or how you saved your images. Add images that might help us understand your scene.

Comment: @cegaton i'll work on that since the file is quite heavy, however i see now difference when the Normalize in the original file and when imported to another. it seems like the defocus node (using Z buffer) just don't work.